# merge two sorted arrays in-place in ascending order

Tags: sorting, merge

merge two sorted arrays in-place in ascending order.
Eg:

```
A[]=7,15,21
B[]=5,12
```

Output

```
A[]=5,7,12
B[]=15,21
```

You can't take any extra memory space except few variables.

Comment: This isn't really merging... As such, find any relevant sorting algorithm and just add some extra functionality to it so that it looks across two arrays instead of just one.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check [In-place merge of two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4553090/133414)) and http://www.dcs.kcl.ac.uk/technical-reports/papers/TR-04-05.pdf. [How to merge two sorted arrays into a sorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5958169/1334148) is a simpler version of it.